# Insert in admin critical documentation for my module

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, uicomponent, documentation

My module has an import CSV functionality and I would like to explain in ~10 lines how that csv should be formatted, max size etc.

I am using ui components.

There is this `<item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">` which is usefull, but provides only on line, so it is not enough.

There is also:

```
  $this->messageManager->addNotice(
            __("Make sure your file is ...")
        );
```

but it is too much to provide 10 notices like that on the screen.

Ideally I would want a help button and then a modal will appear. Is it possible to build that in my grid using ui components?

Thanks